# How to get Activity Class from intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Suppose there is an application with package name `com.example`.

The application has an activity which has an intent filter `android.intent.action.SEND`

Now I want to programatically find the component class that supports the above intent filter.

This code filters all the classes that matches ACTION_SEND.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But, I want to choose the activity only from the package that matches `com.example`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PackageManager can be retrieved with [Context.getPackageManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageManager%28%29) and [queryIntentActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) with the intent you are considering will return the ResolveInfo of Activities that can perform that intent.

[ResolveInfo.activityInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html#activityInfo) will give you the ActivityInfo which has [packageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#packageName) which is what you are looking to filter on.

Once you have selected the target you want, you can make the [ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) for that activity using the package name and class and [setComponent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29) on the desired intent to explicitly target the activity you want.

Comment: I got the list of ResolveInfo. How to get the name of the class?? I tried `resolveinfo.activityInfo.targetActivity` and `resolveinfo.activityInfo.parentActivityName` but both returned `null`.

Comment: Got it. `resolveinfo.activityInfo.name` is the class name to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it. Get the list of all the packages that support the intent.

```
List<ResolveInfo> rInfo =  getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(createShareIntent(),0);
for(ResolveInfo r:rInfo){
    if(r.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.example")){

        chosenName = new ComponentName( r.activityInfo.packageName,
                r.activityInfo.name);
        break;
    }
}

Intent choiceIntent = new Intent(createShareIntent());
choiceIntent.setComponent(chosenName);
startActivity(choiceIntent);
```

**Create share intent**

```
private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Message");
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject...");
    return shareIntent;
}
```