# Get a list of posible app to share content on android

Tags: android

when i use intent.ActionSend , android shows a dialog, with all of posibles places to send this content.

[image: Android share list]

I would like to know if it is posible to take this list of all applications ,where i can share, and have something like:

```
List<String> shareoptions --> {com.facebook, com.gmail, com.whatever...}
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18379090/786337):

```
List<ResolveInfo> rInfo =  getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(createShareIntent(),0);

private Intent createShareIntent() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Text to share");
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        return shareIntent;
    }


List<String> shareoptions = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

To get the list of package name:

```
for(ResolveInfo r:rInfo){
 String packageName = r.activityInfo.packageName;
 // do whatever you want to do here. Populate your own list view
 shareoptions.add(packageName);
}
```